# How to get Unique value in blade file laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to fetch unique value for filters of all products.

My db structure as follows

```
id   Product category_id format   attribute
1     demo1      5         HD      test1
2     demmo2     4         SD      test3
3     demmo3     4         HD      test2
4     demmo4     3         HD      test3
```

I want add filters of format and attribute in product page. But in that HD comming 3 times. I want to display that one only.

I am not getting how to display only single time.

Below is my controller code:

```
$item = Item::where('active_status', 1)->where('status', "1");
$data['item_count'] = $item;
$data['item'] = $item->paginate(20);
return view('frontend.pages.explore', compact('data'));
```

Below is blade file

```
<div class="filter-btn">
  @foreach($data['item'] as $resolution)
      <a class="btn btn-white-outline display-4" href="">{{array_unique($resolution->format)}}</a>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

I am not getting how to display unique value only. Anyone have idea then let me know

Comment: I cannot understand you query. You are using where query with active_status and status but you do not have column on the table. Please make your query clear.

Comment: @Prajwal Bati I am just giving demo table structure. Its actually product status to display

Comment: @Praful Use GroupBy for your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are paginating your data, your "first page" might not have all the formats, so you have to do  another query to your database:

```
$formats = DB::table('items')->select('format')->distinct()->get()
...
view(..., compact('data', 'formats'))
```

in the blade table:

```
@foreach($formats as $resolution)
  <a class="btn btn-white-outline display-4" href="">{{$resolution->format}}</a>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I am not getting your exact point

Comment: [{"format":null},{"format":"4K"},{"format":"HD"}] .. I am getting data in this format

Comment: How to display json data into blade with decode foreach

Comment: @Praful try it now

Comment: Same distinct keyword using in query. I am getting unique value. But in foreach getting error. Foreach not working proper bcoz data comming in json format i think.. See this data i am getting in $formats variable  --------    [{"format":null},{"format":"4K"},{"format":"HD"}]

Comment: @Praful yes that's correct, what's the problem? if you use the blade script i provided you, it should work fine

Comment: $formats output like this : [{"format":null},{"format":"4K"},{"format":"HD"}]

Comment: If i apply foreach loop to $formats then getting error . Its not working

Comment: @Praful and that's correct, what's the problem? please copy paste the blade code, be sure it includes `->format` in the `{{$resolution}}` part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238090/discussion-between-praful-and-alberto-sinigaglia).

Comment: @foreach(json_decode($formats, true) as $data)

                                    <a class="btn btn-white-outline display-4" href="">{{ $data['format'])}}</a>
                                @endforeach

Comment: @Praful and it's working? it's not supposed to

Comment: Means? I am not getting your point

Comment: @Praful the code I'm providing you is working? if not, which error are you getting (please do not paraphrase the error, answer with the actual error)

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct about your query, then you need to use groupby to list the items in your controller.

```
$items = Item::groupBy('format')->get();
```

Comment: But i want to display all the product also . I want show format or attributes as filter in left div and in right div show products. So  i want show like that

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to create a sperate model for `Format`and relationship between it and Product or whatever model that needs format , then fetch formats from its table and apply eager load .

this may look longer than your solution , but this is standards shoiuld be taken for vrious reasons :

- less sql queries
- more flexibility and options regarding our new table
- better and less code to crud format
- single source for change
- less database data and faster load
- ...

### Product.php

```
public function format(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Format::class);
}
```

### Format.php

```
public function products(){
  return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

### Usage

##### in controller

```
// get all formts eager loaded with products 
$formats = Format::with('products')->get();
//get all products
$product = Format::latest()->paginate(20);
return view('frontend.pages.explore', compact( 'products' ,'formats'));
```

##### in your view

```
// all prodcuts 
@foreach($formats as $format)
  <a class="btn btn-white-outline display-4" href="">{{$format->name}}</a>
@endforeach

// in filter ( at clicking ) no additional query
@foreach($format->products as $product)
  ...
@endforeach
```